# How to enlarge ONLY a letter of a word in R

Tags: r, function, plot

**Background:**

It often happens that when you plot an equation consisting of letters (e.g., ***t***), parentheses and numbers, some letters look much smaller than parentheses and numbers.

**Question:**

I'm wondering if there is a way in R to magnify (enlarge) only the letter ***"t"*** in my R code below to overcome the problem I described in the Background (**see my R code below**)?

[image]

**Here is my R code:**

```
par(family = "serif")
plot(1:10, ty='n')

mtext(bquote(italic("t")*(.(11))*" = "*.(2.78)* ",  "*italic("p")*" = "*.(.032)*",  
"*italic("d")*" = "*.(.66)*",  " *"95% "*CI[~italic((d))]* " ["*.(.42)*",  "* .(1.23)*"]" ) 
, side = 1, line = -15, at = 2, adj = 0, cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: Googling "enlarge cex" can lead to surprising results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text` instead of `mtext`. One advantage is that if you had to enlarge some other letter in the middle, you can split the whole text into two groups and use `strwidth` to find out the position of the letter you want to enlarge. In this  case, since the letter you want to enlarge is at the beginning, you can just write the whole text in just two steps. First write the longer text at certain x an y with and then write the text at the beginning with appropriate `adj` and `cex`. Read about `adj` at `?text`.

```
graphics.off()
par(family = "serif")
plot(1:10, ty='n')

text(x = 2, y = 6, labels = bquote(italic("")*(.(11))*" = "*.(2.78)* ",  "*italic("p")*" = "*.(.032)*","*italic("d")*" = "*.(.66)*",  " *"95% "*CI[~italic((d))]* " ["*.(.42)*",  "* .(1.23)*"]" ), adj = 0, cex = 1.5)

text(x = 2, y = 6, labels = expression(italic("t")), adj = c(1, 0.2), cex = 5)
```

---

To demonstrate what I meant by being able to enlarge letters in middle, here's an example where I enlarged "p" in the middle

```
graphics.off()
windows(width = 8, height = 6, pointsize = 10)
par(family = "serif")
plot(1:10, ty='n', asp = 1)

text(x = 1, y = 6, labels = bquote(italic("t")*(.(11))*" = "*.(2.78)* ",  "), adj = 0, cex = 1.5)

w1 = strwidth(bquote(italic("t")*(.(11))*" = "*.(2.78)* ",  "), cex = 1.5)

text(x = 1+w1, y = 6, labels = bquote(italic("p")), adj = 0, cex = 5)

w2 = strwidth(bquote(italic("p")), cex = 5)

text(x = 1+w1+w2, y = 6, labels = bquote(" = "*.(.032)*","*italic("d")*" = "*.(.66)*",  " *"95% "*CI[~italic((d))]* " ["*.(.42)*",  "* .(1.23)*"]" ), adj = 0, cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: This is a better general solution than mine. Too bad code-golf wasn't the goal :-) (I had considered pursuing this method too, but since (a) OP was using `mtext`, and (b) had limited time, I opted for the simpler method. Thanks for taking the time to "do it better"!)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to change just the first letter, it can be relatively easy. Place the enlarged letter at the `line`/`at` and *right-justified*, and place the remainder of the string at the same `line`/`at` and *left-justified*.

```
par(family = "serif")
plot(1:10, ty='n')
at <- 1.5
line <- -4
mtext(bquote(italic("t")), side = 1, line = line, at = at, adj = 1, cex = 5)
mtext(bquote((.(11))*" = "*.(2.78)), side = 1, line = line, at = at, adj = 0, cex = 1.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with mtext by enlarging everything with cex and then reducing the size of all the expression after the "t":

```
mtext(bquote(italic("t")*scriptscriptstyle( (.(11))*" = "*.(2.78)* ",  "*italic("p")*" = "*.(.032)*",  
"*italic("d")*" = "*.(.66)*",  " *"95% "*CI[~italic((d))]* " ["*.(.42)*",  "* .(1.23)*"]" ) )
, side = 1, line = -15, at = 2, adj = 0, cex = 3)
```